# creating inteval object in r using lubridate package

Tags: r, database, time, intervals, lubridate

hi i have data from uber :
[image]

about pick ups in NYC . 
im trying to add a column to the raw data, that indicates for each row, for
which time interval (which is represented by a single timepoint at the beginning of thetime interval) it belongs.

i want to Create a vector containing all relevant timepoints (i.e. every 15 minutes 
Use int_diff function from lubridate package on this vector to create an
interval object.
 Run a loop on all the time points in the raw data and for each data
point; indicate to which interval (which is represented by a single
timepoint at the beginning of the time interval) it belongs.

i tried looking for explanations how to use the int_diff function but i dont understand how my vector should look and how the syntax of int_diff works 
 tanks for the help :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but it sounds like it could be simpler to add a column like `mutate(Datetime_rnd = lubridate::floor_date(DateTime, "15 minutes")`. This will be "the interval [to which]... it belongs."

Comment: @RonakShah: Looks like the dupe target you picked has been deleted. Could you please edit the dupe banner to point straight to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54093675/indicateing-to-which-interval-a-date-belongs?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you have in mind?

```
start <- mdy_hm('4/11/2014 0:00') # start of the period
end <- mdy_hm('5/12/2015 0:00') # end
time_seq <- seq(from = start, to = end, by = '15 mins') # sequence by 15 minutes

times <- mdy_hm(c('4/11/2014 0:12', '4/11/2014 1:24')) # times to find intervals for
dat <- data.frame(times)

dat$intervals <- cut(times, breaks = time_seq) # assign each time to an interval

intervals_cols <- model.matrix(~ - + intervals, dat) # turn this into a set of columns, one for each interval, with a 1 indicating that this observation falls into the column
```

Comment: Yes for example if i have time ,03:41 there will be  a new column in the data  and this will be assined to the 03:00 interval (  interval for every 15 minutes)

Comment: How can i do that ? Using int_dif or any other functions ?

Comment: So you want a column for every interval? I edited my response to show how to turn these intervals into columns.

Comment: Not a column for every interval but a column containing all the intervals according to the original time :

Comment: For example 06:50-----06:45

Comment: Can you post an example of what that might look like? What the original data would have been and the transformed data?

Comment: Date/Time Lat Lon Base              the  column I want to add
4/1/2014 0:11 40.769 -73.9549 B02512 0:00
4/1/2014 0:17 40.7267 -74.0345 B02512 0:15
4/1/2014 0:21 40.7316 -73.9873 B02512 0:15
4/1/2014 0:28 40.7588 -73.9776 B02512 0:15
4/1/2014 0:33 40.7594 -73.9722 B02512 0:30
4/1/2014 0:33 40.7383 -74.0403 B02512 0:30
4/1/2014 0:39 40.7223 -73.9887 B02512 0:30
4/1/2014 0:45 40.762 -73.979 B02512 0:45
4/1/2014 0:55 40.7524 -73.996 B02512 0:45
4/1/2014 1:01 40.7575 -73.9846 B02512 0:45

Comment: Okay, the code I gave you up through `dat$intervals` should do that.