# indicateing to which interval a date belongs

Tags: r, loops, time, intervals

```
4/1/2014 0:11   40.769  -73.9549    B02512|
4/1/2014 0:17   40.7267 -74.0345    B02512|
4/1/2014 0:21   40.7316 -73.9873    B02512|
4/1/2014 0:28   40.7588 -73.9776    B02512|
4/1/2014 0:33   40.7594 -73.9722    B02512|
4/1/2014 0:33   40.7383 -74.0403    B02512|
```

and i created a time interval objet that lokks like this 
`C--2014-04-11 00:15:00 UTC 2014-04-11 00:15:00 UTC`(part of it )
 what i want to do is to to add a column to the raw data, that indicates for each row, for
which time interval (which is represented by a single timepoint at the beginning of the
time interval) it belongs

so my data would look like this :

```
4/1/2014 0:11   40.769  -73.9549    B02512  4/1/2014 0:00|
4/1/2014 0:17   40.7267 -74.0345    B02512  4/1/2014 0:15|
```

how can i do that ?

Comment: Isn't this the same question you posted ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54093148/assigning-time-to-a-time-interval-in-r

Comment: Are all intervals 15 minutes long? If so you can just use floor.

Comment: yes all the intervals are 15 minutes long ,  i tried running  a for loop  but it didint work

Comment: Now I see you got the exact same answer as mine on yet ANOTHER question you posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066057/creating-inteval-object-in-r-using-lubridate-package

Answer (score 1):

Using `lubridate`'s `floor_date` function:

```
df$interv<-lubridate::floor_date(df$time, unit="15 minutes")
```

(This assumes that your time column is some recognized date-time format (e.g., POSIXt), which it doesn't seem to be from your sample's formatting.)

For example:

```
a<-Sys.time()
a
[1] "2019-01-08 09:22:22 EST"
floor_date(a,unit="15 minutes")
[1] "2019-01-08 09:15:00 EST"
```